# "/private/etc/my.cnf" E212: Can't open file for writing

Tags: permissions, osx, configuration

I want to add the `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` to my.cnf file:
My steps:

1)

```
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

2）add this line in the my.cnf:

```
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

3) but when I use `:wq` to quit:

I get this issue:

> "/private/etc/my.cnf" E212: Can't open file for writing

---

[image]

Then I press enter it will go back to the my.cnf's content.

---

**Additional -1**

```
$ id
```

> aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ id 
>   uid=501(ldl) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)

**Additional -2**

```
$ ls -l /private/etc/my.cnf
```

> ls: /private/etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory

---

**Additional -3**

In my `mysql/support-files`

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /etc /etc/my.cfg`?

Comment: There is some inconsistency, some times `/private` sometimes not. Is this just copy error? or is it part of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously don't have write access to mentioned file. To check it do:

```
ls -l /private/etc/my.cnf
```

To get know which user you are using use `id` command. You should either be an owner of the file or belong to the group that has write access (w letter in ls output) to this file.

Of course, you should be able to escalate your privileges to write this file. Use `sudo` or log in as a root.

Edit1:

Och, so you are using OSX :)
According to [MySQL settings on OSX](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017#msg-376017) you need to create /etc/my.cnf file. You will have to use `sudo` to do that. So `sudo vi /etc/my.cnf`.
Note, that if this file is not present, then it would be wise to copy example configuration file as mentioned in above link and then edit it:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-huge.cnf /etc/my.cnf
sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Sudo will ask for your administrator password (at least according to online help). This account needs to have password set.

Edit2:

File my-default.cnf looks good. Copy it to /etc/my.cnf and start editing.

```
sudo cp my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: I have add more information to my post, have a look.

Comment: @aircraft, answer updated.

Comment: but when I execute copy, issue: `cp: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-huge.cnf: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Aircraft, Did you check directory? You can do it with `ls` command. Do you have MySQL installed?

Comment: see my ` Addtional -3`

Comment: don't do `sudo vi «file-name»`, instead do EDITOR=vi sudoedit «file-name»`. Maybe even use a different editor to `vi`.